# Disable woocommerce order processing email for virtual orders only

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to utilise the code below to stop woocommerce from sending the order processing email for virtual products only.

```
function disable_virtual_order_emails( $order ) {
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ) {
        $product = $order_item->get_product();
        if ( $product && $product->is_virtual() ) {
            // If the order contains a virtual product, remove the order processing email
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_notification', array( $order->get_email_recipients(), 'trigger' ) );
            break;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'disable_virtual_order_emails' );
```

However when checking out I get an error

> Error processing checkout. Please try again.

I've tried to enable debug and print it to screen to see what the error actually is however it is not displaying anything.

I also found this code on stackoverflow from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74845492/disable-order-received-emails-for-virtual-products) :

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wpd_autocomplete_virtual_orders', 10, 1 );
function wpd_autocomplete_virtual_orders( $order_id ) {
 

        if( ! $order_id ) return;
     
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     
        // get order items = each product in the order
        $items = $order->get_items();
     
        // Set variable
        $only_virtual = true;
     
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
             
            // Get product id
            $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
     
            // Is virtual
            $is_virtual = $product->is_virtual();
     
            // Is_downloadable
            $is_downloadable = $product->is_downloadable();
     
            if ( ! $is_virtual && ! $is_downloadable  ) {
     
                $only_virtual = false;
     
            }
     
        }
     
        // true
        if ( $only_virtual ) {
     
            wp_update_post(['ID' => $order_id, 'post_status' => 'wc-completed']);
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_processing_order', '__return_false' );
     
        }
    }
```

However none of the suggestion there seem to do the trick either. The order does get marked as complete but the order processing email still comes through.

Some help to get this working or any other code that can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Manage to figure this one out for anyone else who may need it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_process_for_virtual_products' );

function my_custom_checkout_process_for_virtual_products() {

    // Check if the cart contains virtual products only
    $virtual_products_only = true;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) {
            $virtual_products_only = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the cart contains virtual products only, remove email notifications
    if ( $virtual_products_only ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_those_pesky_emails' );
        function unhook_those_pesky_emails( $email_class ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

To remove order completed email simply add after or replace

```
remove_action('woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger'
```

With

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
```

Comment: This work perfectly, although I am trying to remove the order complete email because the booking plugin is handling that already.  can you help with the code modification?

Comment: @BodaWale sorry just saw this. Edited the answer to add this as well.